# How to make a a random response in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I just wanna make a command where you ask a question and it answers with yes or no
`i didn’t try anything`

Comment: Just saying my commands are setup like.                ```case “8ball”:                                                                       Msg.channel.send(“SomeText”);                                          Break;```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have to options, you can use `Math.random()` and the `ternary operator`

```js
Math.random() < 0.5 ? message.channel.send('yes') : message.channel.send('no');
```

Basically, `Math.random()` will generate a (pseudo)random number between 1 and 0. `Math.random() < 0.5` is essentially a fifty-fifty chance.

Answer (score 0):

Just have an array which stores your answers.

```
let answers = [
    'answer 1'
    'answer 2'
];
```

and then just have it choose a random one from that using

```
let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(answers.length));
message.reply(answer[index]);
```

Comment: Ok this worked. Thx so much!

Ok I see ```Math.random() < 0.5 ? message.channel.send('yes')   :message.channel.send('no');```

Comment: How do I make it choose between 10 different messages?

Comment: Put 10 messages in the array